# Top level await not working with ESM in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm using [this benchmark](https://github.com/noctjs/ecs-benchmark) however when running `src/bench.js` Node throws this error:

```
      let result = await run_bench(path, config);
                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:21)
```

Top level await is supposed to work in ESM modules, and the `package.json` definitely has `"type": "module"`. I also tried using `mjs` but still didn't work.

This isn't my code, so I'm unsure how to even start to fix it.

I'm using Node.js v14.4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for top level await (without passing a command line argument to enable it as an experimental feature) was [introduced](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.8.0/) in Node.js 14.8.0.

The version of Node.js you are using is too old.

Comment: Actually I found it: it's `--harmony-top-level-await`. You might want to add that to the answer